# How to get innerText in javascript when elements are supplied in runtime?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get the `innerText` of an element but it's returning `undefined`.

code:

```
 <td id="some-id"><obs conceptId="3156" style="textarea"/>(this one here inserts the span element)</td>
```

generated html during runtime:

```
 <td id="some-id"><span class="value">14</span></td>
```

I have tried using `document.getElementById("some-id").innerText` result was `undefined`.
I have tried using `document.getElementById("some-id").innerHTML` result was `<span class="value">14</span>`. I would like to get the value 14.

Comment: Have you tried `getElementById("some-id")`?

Comment: Then just add the id to your `<span>` block (i.e : ` <td id="some-id"><span id="another-id" class="value">14</span></td>` and `document.getElementById("another-id").innerHTML` will return 14, `document.getElementById("some-id").innerHTML` will return `<span id="another-id" class="value">14</span>`)

Comment: I think I'm targeting the span that's why it's returning undefined. Span is inserted during runtime how can I go one step deeper to get the value 14.

Comment: You need to show a complete example. It's very unlikely that `innerHTML` contains something but `innerText` is undefined.

Comment: When you insert your span, just insert it with an id

Comment: @Ploutox span is generated by the application i'm using.

Comment: @Ploutox It shouldn't make any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cJ79c/)***
*Javascript*

```
var td = document.getElementById('some-id');
alert(td.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML);
```

And your question about `innerText` it will work only in IE, as per I know Firefox and Chrome uses [`textContent`](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/prop_element_textcontent.asp)

***[Fiddle with textContent](http://jsfiddle.net/cJ79c/1/)***

Hope it helps..!!

Comment: Please do not use `<kbd>` tags to decorate your answer. Those tags are used to denote user input, and not hyperlinks.

Answer (score 1):

> I think I'm targeting the span that's why it's returning undefined. Span is inserted during runtime how can I go one step deeper to get the value 14.

Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/8sr2D/1/

If

```
<table>
  <td id="some-id"><span class="value">14</span></td>
</table>
```

will always be the situation, then I think:

```
function getValueForTd(id) {
    var element = document.getElementById(id);
    var span = element.childNodes[0];

    if(span !== undefined) {
        var value = span.innerText;
        return value;
    }   

    return false;
}
```

should get you your value.

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

document.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].innerHTML

Comment: This is quite exceptional. So how does the HTML contents of the document's first `<p>` tag help with getting the text contents of a table cell?

Comment: you should use this inside a for loop so that you can get values of entire span tag present in the table