# Styling not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to display the first element as different color. I am able to do that but `onalert`, it is showing the number and style together and not only the number. I want to alert only `1`. My code is:

```
function shuffleArray(array) {
    for (var i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
            var temp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[j];
            array[j] = temp;
            }
        return array;
    }

var myArray = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10'];

newArray = myArray;

for (i=0;i<newArray.length;i++) {
    var p = document.createElement('p');
    var  color = "green";

    if((i == 0) || (i ==1) || (i == 2) || (i ==3)){
    p.innerHTML = "<p style='color:"+color+"'>"+newArray[i]+"</p>";
    }
    else{
        p.innerHTML = newArray[i];
    }
    p.onclick = showAlert; 
    document.body.appendChild(p);
}

         function showAlert() {
                  alert("onclick Event detected! " + this.innerHTML);
         }
```

Here's [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rani89/92fRb/13/). On clicking element other than `1`, it shows me the number clicked but on clicking `1` it shows me `<p style="color:green">1</p>`.

Comment: Well.. that isn't so strange because you put that code there. `p.innerHTML = "<p style='color:"+color+"'>"+newArray[i]+"</p>";`. Thats your `.innerHTML`.

Comment: So, how can I style only the first 4 elements?

Comment: I really doubt you want nested `<p>`,   set the style on the element itslef instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change alert to `innerText`

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/92fRb/10/)

Answer (score 0):

Try This:-

```
alert("onclick Event detected! " + this.textContent);
```

Answer (score 0):

### [*Updated Fiddle*](http://jsfiddle.net/92fRb/11/)

*Update Javascript*

```
 function showAlert() {
          alert("onclick Event detected! " + this.textContent);
 }
```

[**More Detailed answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23950688/2260614)

Answer (score 0):

try innerText, so your showAlert-Function would look like this:

```
function showAlert() {
    alert("onclick Event detected! " + this.innerText);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hey instead of **innerHTML** use **textContent**

```
`function showAlert() 
{
    alert("onclick Event detected! " + this.textContent)
}`
```